# Count items in one array in another array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given the values in `C`, I want to count how many times I encounter each of these values in the vector `B`.  For example, if `C = [1 2]`, I'd like to count how many "1"s are in B and how many "2"s are in B by checking the elements of array C.

However, the code I have seems to count up to 5, but what the true output should be is that the number of 1s is 2 and the number of 2s is 3.

The code I wrote is shown below.  Any help would be certainly appreciated.

**My code :**

```
 B = [ 1 2 1 4 5 2 2 ]
 C = [ 1 2 ]

 lb = length(B)
 lc = length(C)

for i = 1:length(B)
    for j = 1:length(C)
      if B(1,i)==C(1,j)
          c=c+1
          A(i)=c
      end 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Santhan Salai gave the corrected answer if you want to stick with loops.  However, for efficiency, you could achieve what you want with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) if you don't want to loop:

```
>> B = [ 1 2 1 4 5 2 2 ];
>> C = [ 1 2 ];
>> D = sum(bsxfun(@eq, B, C.'), 2)

D =

     2
     3
```

`bsxfun` is a nice tool that allows you to broadcast data across singleton dimensions.  In our case, I used the `equals` functions to check for element-wise equality and I transposed `C` so that it becomes a column vector.  What will be produced is a matrix where we have as many rows as there are in `C` and as many columns as there are in `B`.  Each row of this output matrix tells you which elements were equal to each corresponding element in `C`.  `C` is **broadcasted** such that we get a matrix of a bunch of `[1;2]` columns mashed together for as many elements as there are in `B` and `B` is broadcasted such that we get replicates of `B` with as many rows as there are in `C`.  By doing element-wise equality, we would produce a logical matrix where each element for a row tells you which elements were equal to the corresponding value of `C`.  All you have to do now is sum over the columns to get how many elements were equal to each value in `C`, hence the `sum` call over the second dimension.

---

If you want overkill, you can also use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  Assuming that `B` and `C` only consist of integers, do:

```
>> B = [ 1 2 1 4 5 2 2 ];
>> C = [ 1 2 ];
>> D = accumarray(B.', 1);    

D =

     2
     3
     0
     1
     1
```

This however computes the frequency of all unique values in `B`, and so you'd just want the first two entries in `D`.

---

One more alternative is to use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
>> B = [ 1 2 1 4 5 2 2 ];
>> C = [ 1 2 ];
>> D = histc(B, C)

D =

   2     3
```

What you are basically computing is a histogram of `B` at specified bins, which are denoted at `C`.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Thank you!  Also good job debugging the loop code.  I was about to correct it, but you already did it for me lol.

Comment: Great answer! Just a comment: `accumarray` will only work for integer values (unless you precede it with `unique`, third output)

Comment: @LuisMendo ohhh good point! I assumed the input would be integer. I'll modify my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `arrayfun` could be one alternate to your loop

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) sum(ismember(B,x)), C)
```

Here is your corrected loop

```
count = zeros(1,numel(C));
for ii = 1:numel(C)
    for jj = 1:numel(B)
        if (C(ii) == B(jj))
            count(ii) = count(ii) + 1;
        end
    end
end
```